# How do I use batchUpdate to both insert a new row at the top and then insert 5 cells of data?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm working on using the Google Sheets Client library to insert a new row into a spreadsheet and then write some data in the top row (but below the header row.)

The batchUpdate method is supposed to allow those using it to combine operations in a way such that if one fails, the other operations will also fail.  This is best in my case since I don't want to insert data on row 2 unless I've successfully inserted a new row at the top first.

However, I'm not quite getting a couple things about how to use the API properly.  The result is that a new row is inserted at the top, but only one of my data points is writing to the first cell, but not all 5 cells in the row.  Here is the API call:

```
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: SHEET_ID,
    "resource": {
        "requests": [
            {
                "insertDimension": {
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": 0,
                        "dimension": "ROWS",
                        "startIndex": 1,
                        "endIndex": 2
                    },
                    "inheritFromBefore": false
                }
            },
            {
                "updateCells": {

                    "rows": 
                        {
                            values: [{
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    stringValue: "Dec 14-Sep 20"
                                },
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    numberValue: 10
                                },
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    numberValue: 5
                                },
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    numberValue: 1
                                },
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    numberValue: 0.2
                                },
                            }]
                        }
                    ,
                    "fields": "*",
                    // "start": {
                    //     "sheetId": 0,
                    //     "rowIndex": 1,
                    //     "columnIndex": 4
                    // },
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": 0,
                        "startRowIndex": 1,  // I want to write to second row only
                        "endRowIndex": 2,
                        "startColumnIndex": 0, // start at first column
                        "endColumnIndex": 5   // end at 5th column
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('No data found.');
    }
});
```

As you can see, I specified a range, but the data; specifically, the last value in the data array, 0.2, is writing to the first column in the sheet.  I also tried using the "start" GridCoordinate instead of the "range" GridRange, but the result is the same.

What do I need to modify to get this to write all 5 values in that data array into the sheet, in one row, one column at a time?

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't in the start or the range properties; instead, the problem is that the object passed into the rows array is not formatted properly.

Now, Google did make the API for modifying cells using batchUpdate quite a bit complicated.  First, in the documentation for [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest) we see that the rows[] array takes a [RowData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#RowData) object.  RowData is an object with the key "values" which contains an array of CellData objects, but each CellData object has to be wrapped up in a set of `{}`.

The CellData object then consists of one or more properties, of which in this case we choose "userEnteredValue".  This contains an [ExtendedValue](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ExtendedValue) object, which can either be number, string, bool, formula, or an error, and it is the last in this complex series of nested objects.

The problem with the above code is that the rows property is labelled as an array in the docs, but it's actually an object containing an array; thus, you're missing the curly braces right after "rows".

Here is what you should have instead:

```
           {
                "updateCells": {
                    "rows":
                    {
                        values: [
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    stringValue: "Dec 14-Sep 20"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    numberValue: 10
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    numberValue: 5
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    numberValue: 1
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    numberValue: 0.2
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    ,
                    "fields": "*",
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": 0,
                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                        "endRowIndex": 2,
                        "startColumnIndex": 0,
                        "endColumnIndex": 5
                    }
                }
            }
```